How to properly calculate distance with Geotools?
I'm trying to calculate the distance between two points but compared to google maps the value is too big. Here is how I do it:
GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator();
gc.setStartingGeographicPoint(59.93748473405807, 10.683153934843533);
gc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(59.949602112593716, 10.731101898029312);

System.out.println(gc.getOrthodromicDistance());

According to google maps and this site the distance should be around 3000m, but what geotools gives me is 5466m which is a huge difference.
I have been also trying to use the approach from this answer but result was around the same (5471m):
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

Point p1 = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(59.93748473405807, 10.683153934843533));
Point p2 = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(59.949602112593716, 10.731101898029312));

try {
  CoordinateReferenceSystem auto = CRS.decode("AUTO:42001,59.93748473405807,10.683153934843533");
  MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, auto);

  Geometry p3 = JTS.transform(p1, transform);
  Geometry p4 = JTS.transform(p2, transform);

  System.out.println(p3.distance(p4));
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}


What am I doing wrong?

Have you maybe switched lat and lon?

Looks like I switched them indeed. After changing it, the getOrthodromicDistance method returned me exactly 3000m. Thank you!
